# Словообразование

Tags: словообразование

Каким способом образовано слово "улетучиться". От какого слова?

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос был конкретный: от какого слова и каким способом. 
Если нужно определить способ словообразования возвратного приставочного глагола, помогает такой прием. Отбрасываем -ся. Смотрим на то, что осталось. В языке такое слово есть? Способ суффиксальный. (умываться от умывать. например). Нет? Приставочно-суффиксальный. (Засмотреться. Засмотреть - нет такого слова. Следовательно. способ приставочно-суффиксальный от слова смотреть). 
Вернемся к слову улетучиваться. Есть ли в языке "улетучивать"? Не думаю. Но смотрю в словарь. Оказывается, есть, с пометой "специальное" - дать исчезнуть, обратив в газообразное состояние, пар (Словарь Ушакова). Следовательно, способ образования суффиксальный.

Меня такое мое рассуждение не подводило. НАйдете ошибку (вообще в рассуждении, не касательно к данному слову), буду рада подсказке. Будем думать дальше.

Comment: Способ образования понятен. А вот вы тоже не ответили,  от какого же слова образовано? "Улетучивать"???? Постройте словообразовательную цепочку. Буду очень признательна. Кстати, это задание из учебника 6 класса. Предлагают обозначить в данном слове части, с помощью которых оно образовано. И как объяснить это детям? "Улетучивать"- малоупотребительное слово.

Comment: Лет(а)ть - летучий (суфф. -уч-) - улетучить (префикс.-суфф.) -  улетучиться (суфф.). Учитывая предыдущие ответы, получила вот это. 
Да, в словах лет(а)ть - лет(е)ть перед -ть тематический гласный, я думаю?

Comment: Ну если у меня не поняли, Екатерина все четко расписала! Татьяна, автора учебника не назовете? Учебник- это пособие. Учитель должен все заранее перерешать и давать те упражнения, которые соответствуют уровню развития детей в классе. Считаю, что подобное слово для домашней или контрольной работы ученику 6 класса давать не следует. Разве что какому-нибудь заинтересованному умничке индивидуально, чтобы подумал, поискал ответ самостоятельно.

Answer (score 0):

Глагол *улетучиться* — улетучиваться, выступающий как синоним слова испариться, не отмечен ни одним словарем русского языка до появления словаря Даля. Очевидно, это слово не вошло в широкий литературный оборот до 30—40-х годов XIX в. Улетучиться входит в литературный оборот как глагольное образование от прилагательного *летучий*. Между тем в слове летучий уже в XVIII — начале XIX в. ярко обозначились три основных значения: 1) `Способный летать, наделенный крыльями'. Летучая мышь. //`Способный летать, носиться в воздухе'. Луна освещает снег летучий. Летучий дым. // `Способный быстро двигаться, менять место, как бы летающий, очень подвижный'. Отряды конницы летучей (Пушкин). Летучие отряды. Летучая почта; 2)`Мимолетный, являющийся и быстро исчезающий, скоро протекающий'. Летучая фраза. Стихи, летучих дум небрежные созданья (Пушкин); 3) В химии: `способный превращаться в пары, легко испаряющийся'. Летучее вещество. Летучие масла (ср. сл. 1867—1868, 2, с. 526). Информация взята у Виноградова.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Исчерпывающий ответ.

Comment: Вы серьезно? А где же ответ на собственно Ваши вопросы? 
К Валентину: дословно копируете Виноградова. Почему не ссылаетесь на него?

Comment: Исправился.

Answer (score -1):

Я учусь в 6 классе, и нам задали упражнение 172, а там есть слово "улетучиться".

Решила посмотреть в Интернете и считаю, что цепочка Екатерины Каштановой более правильная. Всё очень чётко и понятно (лично мне).

Comment: Используйте для подобных замечаний комментарии.